# Adding Column from a Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba, addition, rows, cells

Apologies if this may seem like a duplicate, however I am looking for a specific solution for perhaps a common problem.

I have the following code to add rows from a range of cells:

[image]

```
Sub Insert_Matrix_Rows()
    Dim Lr As Integer, Fr As Integer

    Fr = Columns("B").Find(What:="User R", After:=Range("B9")).Row 'Searching row of "User R" header
    Lr = Range("B" & Fr).End(xlDown).Row 'Searching last row in Risk table

    Rows(Lr + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Inserting new row
   'Cells(Lr + 1, "B") = Cells(Lr, "B") + 1 'Adding a sequential number
    Rows(Lr).Copy 'Copying format of last row
    Rows(Lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 'Pasting format to new row
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Deactivating copy mode
    Cells(Lr + 1, "C").Select
End Sub
```

I assign it as a macro and it works to copy the row 9, and paste it below that row. Essentially, I would like to copy this process for columns instead. So that any rows that might be produced by the code above would be included when producing columns, and vice versa.

I have attempted to do translate the code to work for columns but I run into errors (Type Mismatch):

```
  Sub Insert_Matrix_Columns()
    Dim Lc As Integer, Fc As Integer

    Fc = Columns("D").Find(What:="User C", After:=Range("E6")).Column 'Searching row of "User C" header
    Lc = Range("E" & Fr).End(xlRight).Column 'Searching last row in Risk table

    Columns(Lc + 1).Insert Shift:=xlRight 'Inserting new row
   'Cells(Lr + 1, "B") = Cells(Lr, "B") + 1 'Adding a sequential number
    Columns(Lc).Copy 'Copying format of last row
    Columns(Lc + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 'Pasting format to new row
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Deactivating copy mode
    Cells(Lc + 1, "E").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line the error occurs?

Comment: The error occurs on: Sub Insert_Matrix_Columns(), the line that includes "Fc - ..."

Comment: o think somehing is missing in your comment

Comment: Corrected on the comment above ^

Comment: you are searching in column D, after cell in column E

Comment: I am searching column D for the phrases "User C", after which I am looking at column "E" to copy that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
Fc = Columns("D").Find(What:="User C", After:=Range("E6")).Column
```

with

```
Fc = Rows(6).Find(What:="User C", After:=Range("E6")).Column
```

**EDIT:**
here is working code (I reproduced the table) using:

```
Sub Insert_Matrix_Columns()
    Dim lastCol As Range

    Set lastCol = Rows(6).Find(What:="User C").End(xlToRight).EntireColumn

    Columns(lastCol.Column + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
    lastCol.Copy
    Columns(lastCol.Column + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

main problem with your code was using `xlRight` instead of `xlShiftToRight` and `xlToRight` which are respectively -4152, -4161, -4161

Comment: I tried debugging, the error is not on the line: "Lc = ...", I noticed the typo of Fr, I have changed that to Fc, though I still get an error: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: avb, if you try reproducing the table, you may be able to see the problem that I am encountering.

Comment: Hey Avb, Thanks for doing it. I'll try the solution when I get the chance, and I'll accept the answer.